# Node.JS MySQL: No rows back is undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, undefined

Whenever I make a query to mySQL and I get no rows back within my Node.js app (which is expected), I get undefined. Shouldn't I be getting an empty array or some other object?

```
getUserByGoogleID: function(googleID, callback) {
        this.tryConnect().getConnection(function(err, con) {
            var sql = queries.getUserByGoogleID;
            con.query(sql, googleID, function (err, result) {
                con.release();
                if (err) throw err;
                // Call the callback function in the caller of this method so we can do something with this "result"
                return callback(result);
            });
        });
    },
```

I did the same query in my mySQL workbench and I got a row of all nulls.

How can I handle this correctly? Do I check against undefined or is there a better way?

Thanks,

Comment: that row of nulls was shown to you by workbench, it did not exist in db.

Comment: Turns out, the "result" in this method DID return [] which is correct. It was just confusing because the callback (called by the parent) did a result[0], which is undefined!